# Exception when using broker.stop() in ActiveMQ

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I get an exception thrown when I stop the `BrokerService` in my code. I have no active consumers running, but an exception gets thrown when I stop. Below is the exception I get:

```
java.io.EOFException: null
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.unmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:268) ~[activemq-client-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.readCommand(TcpTransport.java:240) ~[activemq-client-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:232) ~[activemq-client-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215) ~[activemq-client-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212]
```

I have got one `JMSTemplate` which sends messages. Here is the code for my `BrokerService`:

```java
@Bean
public BrokerService startAMQBroker(){
    BrokerService broker = null;
    try {
        broker = new BrokerService();
        TransportConnector connector = new TransportConnector();
        connector.setUri(new URI("tcp://localhost:61616"));
        broker.addConnector(connector);
        broker.setPersistent(false);
        broker.setUseJmx(true);
        broker.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return broker;
}
```

Here is the code to stop the broker:

```java
@Component
public class AMQEndPoint implements Endpoints{
    public final JmsIutputEndpoint jmsIutputEndpoint;
    public final JmsOutputEndpoint jmsOutputEndpoint;
    private BrokerService broker;

    public AMQEndPoint(JmsIutputEndpoint jmsOutPutEndpoint, JmsOutputEndpoint jmsOutputEndpoint, BrokerService broker) {
        this.jmsIutputEndpoint = jmsOutPutEndpoint;
        this.jmsOutputEndpoint = jmsOutputEndpoint;
        this.broker = broker;
    }

    public void close(){
        try {
            jmsIutputEndpoint.close();
            broker.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

How can I shut it down cleanly to avoid this exception?

Comment: Are you seeing this exception on the broker itself or one of the clients? Please clarify.

Comment: In the broker itself